# Working with hyperlinks in Aspose.Cells

Tags: c#, .net, aspose-cells

I am generating an excel document using Aspose.Cells, and inside the document some fields will contain a URL. I would like to make the URL a clickable link. I have tried adding the link to the hyperlinks collection using

```
workSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(cell.Name, rowCount, columnCount, content);
```

This will add the link as desired but if the user sorts the document in Excel, the link will remain attached to the cell it originated from. The ability to sort in Excel is a requirement.

I have also tried

```
cell.Formula = $"=HYPERLINK(\"{content}\",\"{content}\")";
```

and then styling the cell as a hyperlink. This works okay, and the links will follow the cell with a sort. The downside is that until the user enables editing in Excel, the link will not be displayed.

Is there a better way to add hyperlinks to Excel with Aspose.Cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following sample code and read its comments. It works fine. Please see the screenshot that shows the output Excel file generated by the code. If you sort the links, they will sort correctly.

**C#**

```
//Create workbook
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

//Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

//Add hyperlink in cell A1
int idx = ws.Hyperlinks.Add("A1", 1, 1, "https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells");
ws.Hyperlinks[idx].TextToDisplay = "Cells Link No: 11";

//Add hyperlink in cell A2
idx = ws.Hyperlinks.Add("A2", 1, 1, "https://forum.aspose.com/c/total");
ws.Hyperlinks[idx].TextToDisplay = "Total Link No: 16";

//Add hyperlink in cell A3
idx = ws.Hyperlinks.Add("A3", 1, 1, "https://forum.aspose.com/c/words");
ws.Hyperlinks[idx].TextToDisplay = "Words Link No: 29";

//Add hyperlink in cell A4
idx = ws.Hyperlinks.Add("A4", 1, 1, "https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf");
ws.Hyperlinks[idx].TextToDisplay = "Pdf Link No: 13";

//Add hyperlink in cell A5
idx = ws.Hyperlinks.Add("A5", 1, 1, "https://forum.aspose.com");
ws.Hyperlinks[idx].TextToDisplay = "Forum Link No: 20";

//Add hyperlink in cell A6
idx = ws.Hyperlinks.Add("A6", 1, 1, "https://forum.aspose.com");
ws.Hyperlinks[idx].TextToDisplay = "Forum Link No: 15";

//Autofit columns
ws.AutoFitColumns();

//Save the output Excel file
wb.Save("output.xlsx");
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: I see, the 2nd and 3rd argument to `Hyperlinks.Add()` is the count for the range of cells that will be hyperlinked; I interpreted it as the count of all cells in the worksheet. Thank you for your fast response!

Comment: I have a variable having rich text i.e. can have bold content, URL, etc. Bold content is coming fine but the URL is coming as text. Please help. I am using a cell.HtmlString